# Internet disconnected during IRobotSoft Task. Use timeout?

Tags: connection

I'm using IRobotSoft Software for Web Scramming. It's a great program but i have a problem.

While I am running a Task, my internet connection went down. When it came up again, the "Get a list of links" task went crazy and then the Robot stopped.

Does anyone know what should I use in the "Get a list of links" property to do a "timeout" and wait till the internet came again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this post: http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl?num=1351094039

> -Create a task named "timeout-refresh".  In the task, add a schedule action, and add an event:
>
> > Event: After each tuple; Condition: _TimeoutN<=100; Name: _TimeoutRetryUrl; Value: refresh; ValueType: String value
>
> -Then in your main task, add an event for your first action:
>
> > Event: After each tuple; Name: _TimeoutTask; Value: timeout-refresh; ValueType: String value
>
> This would allow every timeout to be retried for at least 100 times.  You can change 100 to other values as well.